# jQuery - Mouseenter / Mouseleave Parent / Child Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a parent div with multiple child divs. The parent div has a hover event on mouseover where it reveals some text on the dom. The child div's also have the same functionality.

I've tried mouseover/mouseout and mouseleave ect but they are not quite right for my usage.

When you hover over the parent the message "foo" reveals in the dom
When you hover over the child the message "bar" reveals in the dom
When you hover back to the parent without leaving the parent no message is shown. At this point I'd like it to be reset to have the same functionality as it did originally.

What is the best way to achieve this please? As I don't want to have to rearrange the dom as it'd be very time consuming

Thanks

Comment: we can't guess at 1) Your html , or 2) the script you are using to interact with the html. Show enough code to reproduce issue

Comment: Sorry - I thought the native jquery example would be clear enough for mouseover/out - the reply below has the right code example - it just needs to work as my comment mentioned in reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a guess but this (or something similar) might do as you describe.

```js
$(function(){
    var disabled = false;
    var theMessage = $("#theMessage");
    $("#theParent").on("mouseover",function(e){
        if(e.target.id == "theChild"){
            theMessage.text("bar");
            disabled=true;
        } else if(!disabled) {
            theMessage.text("foo");
        }
    }).on("mouseout",function(e){
       if(e.target.id == "theParent"){
           disabled=false;;
       }
        theMessage.text("...")
    });
});
```

```css
#theParent {width:200px; height:200px; background:red; position:relative;}
#theChild {position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; margin:auto; width:100px; height:100px; background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theMessage">...</div>
<div id="theParent">
    <div id="theChild"></div>
</div>
```

v2:

```js
$(function(){
    var disabled = false;
    var theMessage = $("#theMessage");
    $("#theParent").on("mouseover",function(e){
        if(e.target.id == "theChild"){
            theMessage.text("bar");
        } else {
            theMessage.text("foo");
        }
    }).on("mouseout",function(e){
       if(e.target.id == "theParent"){
           disabled=false;
           theMessage.text("...");
       }
    });
});
```

```css
#theParent {width:200px; height:200px; background:red; position:relative;}
#theChild {position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; margin:auto; width:100px; height:100px; background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theMessage">...</div>
<div id="theParent">
    <div id="theChild"></div>
</div>
```

**v3:** Use the `data-attribute` to store the hover text:

```js
$(function(){
    var theMessage = $("#theMessage");
    var defaultTxt = theMessage.text();
    $("#theParent, #theChild").on("mouseover",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        theMessage.text($(this).data("txt"));
    });
    $("#theParent").on("mouseout",function(){
         theMessage.text(defaultTxt);
    });    
});
```

```css
#theParent {width:200px; height:200px; background:red; position:relative;}
#theChild {position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; margin:auto; width:100px; height:100px; background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theMessage">...</div>
<div id="theParent" data-txt="foo">
    <div id="theChild" data-txt="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly like that but when you move from the child to the outer I want Foo to show again and if I go back to the child without leaving the parent I want Bar to show again - thanks

Comment: Updated my answer. See v3.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vnzunp5w/16/

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

seems to be the winner!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this in order to have the arrows hide initially, and than show them on hover only. 
Using this slider http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.Vk4so7erTRY
(best one I have found so far)

```
$('.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev').addClass('hide');
    var hoverArrows = function(){
        console.log("hoverArrows")
        $('.swiper-wrapper, .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev').mouseenter(function () {
            console.log("hovered")
            $('.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev').removeClass('hide');
        }).mouseleave(function () {
           $('.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev').addClass('hide');
        });
    }
    hoverArrows();
```